# Whenever I use the "playsound" to play sound in the background the rest of my game does not load

Tags: python, python-playsound

I decided to use `playsound()` to add a background sound in my program. However when I run the program with playsound, the actual game does not load until the song is finished:

```
from playsound import playsound
#type 'pip install playsound' in command prompt to install library
import random

playsound('audio.mp3')

while True:
    min = 1
    max = 6
    roll_again = "yes"
    while roll_again == "yes" or roll_again == "y":
        print("Rolling the dices...")
        print("The values are....")
        print(random.randint(min, max))
        print(random.randint(min, max))
        roll_again = raw_input("Roll the dices again?")
```

Usually I would expect the sound to play in the background while the dice game is loaded and being played, however it does not work like this.

Comment: `playsound` isn't part of Python itself. Which library is it from? Add that library to your question's tags. And cut the code down to a [mcve] -- the *shortest possible code* that produces the problem you're asking about when run without changes. Including a MCVE that lets people reproduce the problem also ensures that folks can test their answers, and validate the correctness of answers others propose. See also the [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) definition, which is closely related (albeit not itself part of Stack Overflow's rules).

Comment: (Right now your code doesn't run without changes *at all* -- only a single function is provided with nothing calling it, no `import`s, etc).

Comment: Okay I've done it, hope it helps with finding a solution.

Comment: Yup, that helps a great deal.

Answer (score 4):

From the documentation for [the `playsound` module](https://pypi.org/project/playsound/):

> There’s an optional second argument, `block`, which is set to `True` by default. Setting it to `False` makes the function run asynchronously.

Thus, if you want it to run once in the background, you need to use:

```
playsound('audio.mp3', block=False)
```

...or, if you want it to run *repeatedly* in the background, waiting until one instance finishes before starting the next, you might launch a thread for the purpose:

```
import threading
from playsound import playsound

def loopSound():
    while True:
        playsound('audio.mp3', block=True)

# providing a name for the thread improves usefulness of error messages.
loopThread = threading.Thread(target=loopSound, name='backgroundMusicThread')
loopThread.daemon = True # shut down music thread when the rest of the program exits
loopThread.start()

while True:
    raw_input("Put your gameplay loop here.")
```