# Timer stops updating when an audio is played

Tags: python, tkinter, playsound, gtts

I have used **after()** method to update the time remaining for quiz and converted text of question to audio using **gtts** module and played that using **playsound** module. But when the audio is played timer stops updating. How can I fix it?

```
import playsound
import tkinter
import gtts
import os

def speak_que():
    global audio_no
    sound = gtts.gTTS(question_label["text"], lang = "en")
    file_name = "Audio_" + str(audio_no) + ".mp3"
    sound.save(file_name)
    playsound.playsound(file_name)
    os.remove(file_name)
    audio_no += 1

def change_time():
    pre_time = int(time_label["text"])
    if pre_time != 1:
        time_label.config(text = pre_time-1)
        time_label.after(1000, change_time)
    else:
        window.destroy()

window = tkinter.Tk()
audio_no = 0
time_label = tkinter.Label(window, text = "15")
time_label.after(1000, change_time)
question_label = tkinter.Label(window, text = "What is the sum of 4 and 2")
answer = tkinter.Entry(window)
speak = tkinter.Button(window, text = "Speak", command = speak_que)
time_label.pack()
question_label.pack()
answer.pack()
speak.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: playsound('audio.mp3', block=False) <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54053953/whenever-i-use-the-playsound-to-play-sound-in-the-background-the-rest-of-my-ga>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure your speak_que() routine is completing, if not, you can install the older version of playsound 1.2.2 as the newest version tends to have issues.

```
pip uninstall playsound

pip install playsound==1.2.2
```

Next, if you want the timer to continue during speak_que() (or any two operations in parallel); you'll have to use threading, see below.

```
import playsound
import tkinter
import gtts
import os
from threading import *

def speak_que():
    global audio_no
    sound = gtts.gTTS(question_label["text"], lang = "en")
    file_name = "Audio_" + str(audio_no) + ".mp3"
    sound.save(file_name)
    playsound.playsound(file_name)
    os.remove(file_name)
    audio_no += 1

def threadedSound():
    t1=Thread(target=speak_que)
    t1.start()

def change_time():
    pre_time = int(time_label["text"])
    if pre_time != 1:
        time_label.config(text = pre_time-1)
        time_label.after(1000, change_time)
    else:
        window.destroy()

window = tkinter.Tk()
audio_no = 0
time_label = tkinter.Label(window, text = "15")
time_label.after(1000, change_time)
question_label = tkinter.Label(window, text = "What is the sum of 4 and 2")
answer = tkinter.Entry(window)
speak = tkinter.Button(window, text = "Speak", command = threadedSound)
time_label.pack()
question_label.pack()
answer.pack()
speak.pack()
window.mainloop()
```